# Перевод декартовой системы координат в пиксельную GDI+ c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив точек для построения графика, подскажите пожалуйста способ перевода точек в пиксели , чтобы построить график с помощью графики GDI+

Comment: А какие с этим у вас проблемы?

Comment: не могу понять, как перевести относительно координат панели , как именно вычислить точку отрисовки линии

Comment: важным вопросом является Wpf или Winforms?

Comment: ну вы систему координат на форме представляете? Как вывести 1 точку знаете? Вашу исходную систему координат тоже понимаете? Что вам надо сделать? Сдвинуть, смасштабировать, повернуть на угол или как вы собираетесь ваши точки переносить на форму?

Comment: Andrew, WinForms

Comment: tym32167, на форме панель , нижний левый угол считать как точка с 0;0 и от этой точки построить два графика sin x^2 и cos x + 1, отрезок вводиться вручную , есть пример , но там не понятно для чего некоторые переменные , а хочется разобраться

Comment: график до конца панели , возможность строить два графика одновременно

Comment: ну так и что не получается то тогда? Вы точку на панели можете нарисовать?

Comment: И что непонятно? Вы понимаете алгоритм, у вас даже есть какой-то пример (к которому у вас есть вопросы, но вы не хотите ни код показать, ни вопросы озвучить), тогда какую помощь от сообщества вы ждёте в этом вопросе?

Comment: A K 17  , я не до конца алгоритм понимаю, получаю массивы : количество точек , координаты для точек функции, и вот с переводом проблема